# Adding Children to Container() EaselJS

Tags: javascript, containers, easeljs, typeerror

I am going through some tutorials and experimenting with javascript and more particularly EaselJS. I want to create a number of containers which hold images and a text together. But I get the following error:  *"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"* when I try to add the text and image to the container.

```
    function init() {
        stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");


        for(var i=0; i<container.length; i++) { //looping through creation of objects
            container[i] = new createjs.Container();
            container[i].x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (760 - 40));
            img[i] = new createjs.Bitmap (" choc.png" );
            container.addChild(img[i]);
            txt[i] = new createjs.Text(i, "bold 16px Courier", "#fff");
            txt[i].textAlign = "center";
            txt[i].y = 50;
            container.addChild(txt[i]);
            stage.addChild(container[i]);

        }
```

The errors is on the *container.addChild(img[i]);* line.

Comment: I don't use EaselJS, but I see that you have a space at the beginning of your file name: ` choc.png`. Might that make a difference?

Comment: where is the stage getting updated?

Comment: The space does not really make a difference, and I am updating the the stage with the container after the for loop. I can't seem to solve this problem, I've tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to call `addChild` on your `container` array, instead of on a `Container` instance. I'm fairly certain this is what you intended:

`container[i].addChild(img[i]);`

This is why naming is important. Consider using `containers` or `containerList` instead of `container` as your array name to clarify that it is a collection.